# Working with XML::Parser, what datastructure does it return?

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

I'm attempting to parse some XML in perl, and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to access it. I'm limited to using either `XML::Parser` or `XML::Twig` since this has to deploy on a wide number of RedHat 6 systems without adding any modules so I can't use something more convenient like `XML::Simple`.

The problem is how do I get at the data. The core of the code is this:

```
use XML::Parser;
use Data::Dumper;

# $response_string is a string of XML.
my $xml_parser = new XML::Parser(Style => 'Time');
my $xml_wodge = $xml_parser->parse($response_string);

# Export methods to see what this is.
print Dumper ($xml_wodge);
print "I have a ref type: ", ref($xml_wodge), "\n";
print "I have array size: ", @xml_wodge, "\n";
print "I have hash keys:  ", %xml_wodge, "\n";
print "I have string value: ", $xml_wodge, "\n";
```

This produces some odd output (edited)

```
$VAR1 = [
   [valid XML dump]
];
I have reference type ARRAY
I have array size: 
I have hash keys:
I have string value ARRAY(0x22c5538)
```

The value in `$xml_wodge` is something. The dumper correctly dumps it out, but none of the datastructure primitives I hit it with seem to be returning anything. It detects as Array, but it seems to be a zero-element array, in which a full XML datastructure lurks just out of reach.

How do I reach it?

Comment: It seems to be an array reference. See [References tutorial](http://p3rl.org/perlreftut).

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`! `$xml_wodge` and `@xml_wodge` are different variables.

Comment: The use of [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#STATUS-OF-THIS-MODULE) is discouraged by its own [module documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#STATUS-OF-THIS-MODULE), so I would argue against the classification of it as *"convenient"*.  Of those two options, I would recommend using [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig), although it would depend on the version numbers.

Comment: You spend all this time saying you can't install modules, but your code relies on XML::Parser::Style::Time which doesn't even exist on CPAN.

Comment: Neither XML::Parser nor XML::Twig are core modules (included with Perl).  If you're getting them from the OS package repository, then I'd recommend getting XML::LibXML from the same place and [using that](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=490846)

Comment: @GrantMcLean Doesn't look like I have a XML::LibXML option in my repos. Looks like a better fit for what I'm doing! Dangit.

Comment: Which OS and Perl distro are you using?  On debian-derived linuxes, LibXML is in the `libxml-libxml-perl` package.  On RedHat I think it's `perl-XML-LibXML`.  Strawberry Perl on Windows includes LibXML in the base package and ActiveState include it in their PPM repo if not the base package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba) was correct in the comments, this call is returning an array-reference. Per perlreftut, accessing the array requires:

```
${$xml_wodge}[0]
```

Style syntax.

XML::Parser returns a specifically formatted data-structure. For an XML structure like this:

```
<Top>
  <Mid1 id="thing">
    <Leaf1>"I'm a leaf"</Leaf1>
  </Mid1>
</Top>
```

- Array index 0 would be the string "Top"
- Array index 1 would be another array reference.

  - [1][0] is a hash-reference, with a single key: 'id' with a value of 'thing'.
  - [1][1] is the string "Mid1".
  - [1][2] is another array reference.

Odd indexes are section names, even indexes are array-references to other elements.

In the case of Leaf1:

- Array index 0 is a hash-reference to an empty hash.
- Array index 1 is the string "Leaf1".
- Array index 2 is an array reference.

  - [..][2][0] is a hash reference to an empty hash.
  - [..][2][1] is the value "0" since this element has no name.
  - [..][2][2] is the string "I'm a leaf".

Leaf1's value can be directly accessed through:

```
${${${$xml_wodge}[1]}[2]}[2]}[2]
```

Comment: Note: `${$xml_wodge}[1]` can also be written as: `$xml_wodge->[1]` and the resulting `$xml_wodge->[1]->[2]->[2]->[2]` can be further simplified to: `$xml_wodge->[1][2][2][2]` (although I wouldn't).

Answer (score 0):

You're using XML::Parse wrong.  Read [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/XML-Parser-2.41/Parser.pm).

Specifically, the `->parse()` method is not meant to return anything.  It's meant to populate the XML::Parse object with data.  Then you can use that object.

So, you would do:

```
my $xml_parser = new XML::Parser(Style => 'Time');
$xml_parser->parse($response_string);

# .. Then use $xml_parser
```

Comment: I'm having trouble reconciling "is not meant to return anything" with documentation on the 'Tree' style saying, "Parse will return a parse tree for the document". I'm definitely getting a reference to an object, and it does have some kind of datastructure with my XML in it.

Comment: @sysadmin1138: It likely returns the object itself, as many object classes do. But if you look at the examples at the top of the documentation page, it's clearly not expecting a return value, and the `parse` documentation says nothing about return values.